Why the Moire Brillouin zone (BZ) of twist bilayer graphene is hexangular?
Usually, we have the definition of the basis vectors of Moire BZ, which is
\begin{align}
 \boldsymbol{b}_1^m=\boldsymbol{b}_1-\boldsymbol{b}_1^\theta,\quad\boldsymbol{b}_2^m=\boldsymbol{b}_2-\boldsymbol{b}_2^\theta.
\end{align}
So how it comes from? Also if we have the vectors of hopping direction $\boldsymbol{q}$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{b}_{1}^{m}=\boldsymbol{q}_{b}-\boldsymbol{q}_{tl}=\frac{8\pi\sin(\theta/2)}{3d}(1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2),\quad\boldsymbol{b}_{2}^{m}=\boldsymbol{q}_{tr}-\boldsymbol{q}_{b}=\frac{8\pi\sin(\theta/2)}{3d}(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2).
\end{align}
it is natural to see the angle is $2 \pi/3$. But how can we see the moire BZ is hexangular geometricly.
Also for the basis vectors in real space, how can we get its expression? Can we say the reason why the commensurate configuration of unit cell of twist bilayer graphene is hexangular is to conserve the $C_6$ symmetry?
